# Using OPENPYXL to extract data from an EXCEL file

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have the following code which prints all items from an excel file. What I am wanting to do is enter a name and then search for this name in the spreadsheet and display the price for the corresponding name in column D. The names are listed in column A. The columns I have in my spreadsheet are(Column A: Player, Column B:Team, Column C: points,  Column D: Cost, Column E: position).

What I am aiming to do is search for a players name and print the price for this player.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

print ("Going to execute the script")

workbook = load_workbook("LeaguePlayers.xlsx", use_iterators = True)

name = print(input("Enter player name: "))

for worksheet in workbook:
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if(cell.value != None):
                print (cell.value)           

print ("End of script execution")
```

Comment: What is the actual question? You only need to use read-only mode when working with a very large file.

Comment: I have an Excel file with players names and various attributes for e.g. Rooney, Man Utd, Forward, 126, £12.6.  The cost is in Column E. I can extract all the information from the Excel file as you can see from above. What I want to be able to do is just enter the players name for e.g. Rooney and it should pull the players price from the column E in the Excel file and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
player = raw_input("Enter player name")
wb = load_workbook("LeaguePlayers.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
for cell in ws.columns[0]: # get first column
    if cell.value == player:
        cost = cell.offset(column=4).value
        print("{0} costs {1}".format(player, cost))
        break
```

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion, I can see what the code is doing however, it throws back a invalid syntax error after the break

Comment: It's pseudo-code to give you an idea of how to approach the problem. You could also use `ws.iter_rows(max_col=1)`. Depends on the size of the dataset.

Comment: The error is due to a known (and fixed) bug in 2.2. Use `pip install openpyxl==2.1.5` until 2.2.1 is released.

Comment: is there no way I can get it to work in 2.2.0? My dataset is approx. 700 rows by about 6 columns.

Comment: @Moridiin, please don't edit an answer to add to your question. Asking for clarification should be left to comments, and if you need to add more code, add it to the question post.

Comment: ok i'm sorry. I'm fairly new to this I will try to remember it in future.

Comment: You can avoid using `cell.offset()` by using `cost = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value`

Comment: Thank you Charlie that worked a treat. Can you direct me to any link that will allow me to see working examples of working with Excel files, especially pulling data from certain cells and other useful items to be aware of.

Comment: Whatever's in the current documentation. Otherwise use the mailing list.